# How to set text in recyclerview to the center with animation?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` with expandable elements. When it expands I would like to have the text to align center-horizontally. I have tried to setGravity, but it is in `ConstraintLayout` and maybe because of that, it doesn't work.

Additionally, is it possible to add during this process with any fancy animation?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample to have better understanding to community!!

Comment: Hey @chrisChris can you share the the XML layout you are using, so you can get any appropriate help here?